# How to access Revit Application out of an Execute method in Revit API?

Tags: revit-api

I have been playing with Revit API through pyRevit for quite a while (so, using Python) and I now also need to use C# for some parts of my code.

I am trying to access the VersionNumber property, provided by the Application class. Doing that using pyRevit was quite straightforward, as all I did was

```
app = __revit__.Application
```

That's it. I can do it anywhere, it works fine.

Now, I look at C# examples illustrating this (I'm a total C# beginner, by the way), and all examples seem to indicate the same way of proceeding:

```
UIApplication uiApp = commandData.Application;
Application app = uiApp.Application;
```

with *commandData* being an *ExternalCommandData* object passed as an argument in the *Execute* method of the class.

My question is: how can I access commandData if I'm **not** in the Execute method? i.e. if commandData isn't passed as an argument. Can I just instantiate an Application object, just as I did with Python? How?

Thanks a lot,

Arnaud.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are in a context of Revit's `ExternalCommand` or not you need access to the `UIApplication`. You are correct that `ExternalCommand` provides it via `commandData`. You can also obtain it from an idling event like so:

```
private static void OnIdling(object sender, IdlingEventArgs e)
{
    var app = (UIApplication)sender;
}
```

It is also accessible from an `ExternalEventHandler` `Execute method like so:

```
public void Execute(UIApplication app)
{
}
```